# Hola buena noche, tengo un problema con position fixed, absolute y relative

Tags: html, sass, position

Tengo una pagina hecha con sass con una nav bar por position fixed para mantenerla fija, mi problema es que tengo una galeria de imagenes con un overlay, el cual tiene position rellative y absolute, la cual al pasar mi navbar por encima la imagen queda por encima, cual es mi error Por favor ayuda con el proyecto no se como solucionarlo..
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sass:

```
.proyecto_item{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative; 
    
    &:hover > .overlay{
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    &:hover > .overlay h3{
        margin-top: 5rem;
        margin-bottom: 1.5px;
    }
}
.overlay{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(20 18 58 / 80%);
    transition: all .5s ease-out;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;

    h3{
        text-align: center;
        color: v.$blanco;
        font-weight: v.$bold;
        margin-bottom: 12rem;
        transition: all .8s ease-out;
        margin-top: 2rem;
    }

    p{
        text-align: center;
        color: v.$blanco;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 22rem;
        margin: auto;
    }
    
}
Html:

<section class="contenedor_proyectos">
   <picture class="proyecto_item">
      <source srcset="build/img/FestivalMusica.avif" type="image/avif">
      <source srcset="build/img/FestivalMusica.webp" type="image/webp">
      <img loading="lazy" width="200" height="300" src="build/img/FestivalMusica.png" 
      alt="Festival Musica">
      <div class="overlay">
         <h3>Festival Musica</h3>
         <p>Sitio Web: gulp, sass, node</p>
      </div>
  </picture>
```

Les agradezco su ayuda, Saludos!!

Comment: Entiendo que lo que quieres es que el navbar quede siempre por encima i la capa absolute quede por debajo, juega con los **z-index** en el navbar ponle un `z-index:9999;` y a la capa absolute ponle un `z-index:50;` por ejemplo.

Comment: Muchas gracias.. Si funciono a la perfección !!